# Bash Script IF statement not functioning

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I am currently testing a simple dictionary attack using bash scripts. I have encoded my password "Snake" with sha256sum by simply typing the following command:

```
echo -n Snake | sha256sum
```

This produced the following:

```
aaa73ac7721342eac5212f15feb2d5f7631e28222d8b79ffa835def1b81ff620 *-
```

I then copy pasted the hashed string into the program, but the script is not doing what is intended to do. The script is (Note that I have created a test dictionary text file which only contains 6 lines):

```
echo "Enter:"
read value

cat dict.txt | while read line1
    do
            atax=$(echo -n "$line1" | sha256sum)

            if [[ "$atax" == "$value" ]];
            then
                    echo "Cracked: $line1"
                    exit 1
            fi

    echo "Trying: $line1"

    done
```

Result:

```
Trying: Dog
Trying: Cat
Trying: Rabbit
Trying: Hamster
Trying: Goldfish
Trying: Snake
```

The code should display "Cracked: Snake" and terminate, when it compares the hashed string with the word "Snake". Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: The bug was indeed the DOS lines in my textfile. I made a unix file and the checksums matched. Thanks everyone.

Comment: BTW, running `bash -x yourscript` would give you a better idea of what was going on here.

Comment: ...as another aside, `echo -n` isn't actually good form. The POSIX specification for `echo` describes `-n` as "unspecified", meaning an implementation can do whatever it likes when given that argument -- it can suppress newlines on its output, but it could also print `-n` on output and be just as compliant -- and when running with both the `xpg_echo` and `posix` options enabled, bash's behavior can be just that.

Comment: ...see the aforementioned specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section, which provides alternative suggestions using `printf` to emulate common `echo` usages.

Comment: Can you show us the values of `${#atax}` and `${#value}` ?

Comment: Please edit the question replacing name by line1. You wrote that as a solution but first I only read the question and came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that, as pakistanprogrammerclub points out, you're never initializing `name` (as opposed to `line1`).

Another problem is that `sha256sum` does not just print out the checksum, but also `*-` (meaning "I read the file from standard input in binary mode").

I'm not sure if there's a clean way to get just the checksum — probably there is, but I can't find it — but you can at least write something like this:

```
atax=$(echo -n "$name" | sha256sum | sed 's/ .*//')
```

(using `sed` to strip off everything from the space onwards).

Comment: Or you could use `awk '{print $1}'`, or an invocation of `cut`.

Answer (score 1):

couple issues - the variable name is not set anywhere - do you mean value? Also better form to use redirection instead of cat

```
while read ...; do ... done <dict.txt
```

Variables set by a while loop in a pipeline are not available in the parent shell not the other way around as I mistakenly said before - it's not an issue here though

Comment: Not my downvote. It's true that `name` is not set. It's not true that the subshell does not have access to variables set in the outer shell. (The reverse is true.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I tried what you suggested but it didn't work. EDIT: i didn't downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a cut n paste error - add an echo after the first read

```
echo "value \"$value\""
```

also after atax is set

```
echo "line1 \"$line1\" atax \"$atax\""
```